# CkEditor: is there a method to output the input content

Tags: formatting, ckeditor, output

How can I get the user's input, is here a method to output or encode?

Now what I can do is

```
var content = $('#cke_ckeditor1 iframe').contents().find('.cke_show_borders').clone();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a method that returns editor's content - `editor.getData()` - see [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData).

You can find editor instance in `CKEDITOR.instances` object.

Answer (score 0):

I used reference of itextsharp to use ckeditor.

Declare a hidden text field in html

```
<%= Html.Hidden("EditECurrentComplainText")%>
```

Here inside a div i used a textArea and converted it to ckeditor and then placed value of that ckeditor into a hidden field.

```
<div id="EditECurrentComplain_ckEditor">
                                    <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Current_Complain, new { rows = "10", id = "EditCurrent_ComplainCK" })%>
                                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Current_Complain)%>
                                        <% if (Model.Current_Complain != "")
                                    { %>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                                                CKEDITOR.replace('EditCurrent_ComplainCK');
                                            });
                                        </script>
                                <%} %>
                                 </div>
```

get content of ckeditor into hidden textfield using the following statement

```
$("#EditECurrentComplainText").val(CKEDITOR.instances["EditCurrent_ComplainCK"].getData());
```

and finally used this hiddentext field content as my desired output/input.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need all of that. If you create CKEditor by replacing textarea, then all you need is `editor.updateElement()` ([docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-updateElement)) and then textarea will contain content of the editor.

Comment: Nope. If you have textarea id, then `CKEDITOR.instances.<textareaid>.updateElement()`.